# Angular Unit Testing using Jasmine and Karma, for a switch case

Tags: angular, unit-testing, switch-statement, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular unit testing

I have implemented a method to convert the data type of the column values(which is of type text) of a particular array, into integer or float. And I used a switch case for this in my product component.

Here is my switch method

```js
     export() {
       
        this.getProducts().then(() => {
          let products: Array<Array<any>> = [];
        
        this.productContent = this.productContent.map(product => {
            ProductConfig.forEach(item => {
              let columnValue = product[item.column];
              let valueIsString = isNaN(parseFloat(columnValue));
              if (!valueIsString) {
                switch (item.dataType) {
                  case item.dataType = "Integer": {
                    product[item.column] = parseInt(columnValue);
                    break;
                  }
                  case item.dataType = "Float": {
                    product[item.column] = parseFloat(columnValue);
                    break;
                  }
                  default: {
                    product[item.column] = columnValue;
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            });
            return product;
          });
        
    }
```

The productConfig is implemented as below.

```js
export const ProductConfig
  = [
    { column:"Product Code", dataType: "Integer" },
    { column:"Total Price", dataType: "Float" },
    { column:"Discounted Price", dataType: "Float" },
    { column:"Tax", dataType: "Float" },
  ]
```

How can I write a unit test case for the above method using jasmine and karma?

Comment: kalpi, welcome to SO community! may you please provide a code showing what you already tried to do?

Comment: I meant the code of the unit tests you tried to do (:

Comment: btw, it would be really helpful for you to go through the welcome tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hi @IAfanasov, i have written a unit test before for a OR condition like in this-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68303552/branch-not-covered-angular-unit-test-or-condition .But I have no idea how to write for a Switch case.Can You please help me

Comment: Hi kalpi (: This question was bothering me (: for quite a time I was thinking why is seems wrong to me. And I get it (: I strongly encourage you to try TDD. start like if you don't have a working code. write test case like "for this argument I expect such results after the function invoked". then do the code only for that case. then next test for different argument and different expected results. You won't even think on how to cover a switch statement (: